# Spring Securtiy Authentication Remember me

Tags: spring, authentication, spring-security

I'm having two different log ins, an external and an internal. The external is on an external homepage, so when you log in in you will be redirected to the "main"-page and the internal is on the main page. 
The problem is that when I log in on  the external form got redirected and then go back to the external page it redirects me again because my isAuthenticated() is true. 
so how can I set the isAuthenticated status to false when I'm on my external page.

Do I have to set a "remember_me" to disabled, a different session-authentication-strategy or a different authenticationManager.

Any ideas/hints? thx for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming you have a different set of users.  So, yes, you will need a different authentication manager.  Configure one for internal vs. external and reference them in your `http` configurations.  You will also probably want a different security context.  We use a strategy where some internal users are kept different from external users.  Configure one of your `<http...` sections as normal. But the other should look like this:

```
<bean id="internalSecurityContextRepository" 
    class="org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository">
    <property name="springSecurityContextKey" value="SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT.internal"/>
</bean>
```

Then in your internal configuration make sure you reference the new context repository:

```
<sec:http pattern="/internal/**"
    security-context-repository-ref="internalSecurityContextRepository"
    authentication-manager-ref="internalAuthenticationManager"
    ... other stuff ... />
```

With this configuration, spring will be able to use different authentication managers and different sets of users for internal vs external.